# Data imputation using R

Tags: r, imputation

I need to do multiple imputation to a data set which is similar to the following toy data set.

```
x1=rbinom(20,1,0.5)
x2=rnorm(20,100,2)
x2=x2/max(x2)
x3=rbinom(20,3,0.4)
x4=rnorm(20,0,0.5)

data=data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
data[1,2]=NA
data[10,2]=NA
data[15,2]=NA
data[2,1]=NA
data[12,1]=NA
data[12,3]=NA
data[19,3]=NA
data[20,3]=NA

> data
   x1        x2 x3           x4
1   0        NA  2  0.103982689
2  NA 0.9599301  1 -0.153152527
3   1 0.9563003  0 -0.783492651
4   0 0.9974261  1  0.325931603
5   1 0.9515747  3 -0.769568378
6   1 0.9431853  0  0.336488307
7   0 0.9637072  1  0.383011575
8   0 0.9937089  0 -0.575941420
9   1 0.9357041  3 -0.648096345
10  0        NA  3  0.213382349
11  0 0.9454354  1  0.111094020
12 NA 0.9330617 NA -0.256448985
```

where x1 is a binary variable, x2 is a variables between 0 and 1 and x3 is a ordinal level variable. I did the imputation using `amelia` function from the `Amelia` package. But it seems that the imputed values are not within the desired range.

```
require(Amelia)

imp=amelia(data,m=2)
imp1=imp$imputations[[1]]
imp2=imp$imputations[[2]]
```

For an example, I got values greater than 1 for x1 and x2. Also the values for x1 and x3 does not preserve the categorical nature of the data.

Is it possible to do the imputation for a data set that involves categorical variables (including binary and ordinal variables) and continuous variables within a certain range using R?

Comment: Apart from the fact that I don't know what `amelia` function does exactly, the problem might be that in your data there isn't a single variable specified as categorical, i.e. as a factor variable, and I doubt the function to be so sophisticated that it can read your thoughts.

Comment: @jay.sf Thank you for the comment. I tried by defining the categorical variables as factors and it gave me an error. I think I may need to explore mice package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Amelia` package, named after a famous missing person, imputes values to missing data. The `mice` package, "multiple imputation with chained equations", also imputes values to missing data and can handle categorical data. First we need to create some reproducible data to share using `dput(data)`. I've rounded the values to make it more compact:

```
data <- structure(list(x1 = structure(c(2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), x2 = c(NA, 0.962, 0.951, 0.964, 0.968, 
0.948, 0.96, 0.944, 1, NA, 0.956, 0.944, 0.975, 0.965, NA, 0.928, 
0.975, 0.948, 0.968, 0.958), x3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA
), .Label = c("0", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), x4 = c(0.433, 
0.29, -0.01, -0.092, -0.29, 0.2, 0.284, 0.206, 0.132, -0.024, 
-0.188, 0.57, 0.092, -0.624, 0.241, -0.262, -0.621, -0.888, 0.346, 
-0.043)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

str(data)
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ x1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 NA 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
#  $ x2: num  NA 0.962 0.951 0.964 0.968 0.948 0.96 0.944 1 NA ...
#  $ x3: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
#  $ x4: num  0.433 0.29 -0.01 -0.092 -0.29 0.2 0.284 0.206 0.132 -0.024 ...
```

You can see the first and third variables are factors/categorical.

```
data.imp <- mice(data)
```

The list `data.imp` contains the information to produce 5 sets of data with the missing values imputed. To get the first set:

```
data.imp1 <- complete(data.imp, 1)
str(data.imp1)
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ x1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
#  $ x2: num  0.965 0.962 0.951 0.964 0.968 0.948 0.96 0.944 1 0.962 ...
#  $ x3: Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 2 2 3 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
#  $ x4: num  0.433 0.29 -0.01 -0.092 -0.29 0.2 0.284 0.206 0.132 -0.024 ...
```

Note that the first and third variables are still factors.